# Insert File URL Links to Existing Images that Were Not Originally Linked to Themselves

Tags: images

I hope the title was descriptive of what I'm looking for. I have a client who has been inserting images into hundreds of posts, but choosing "Link URL: None" when inserting images instead of choosing "Link URL: File URL".

Now they want to use our Responsive Lightbox plugin, but of course, since these images aren't linked to their file URLs, our plugin can't pick it up.

Does anyone here know of any plugins, or perhaps a SQL command that we can run that will run through all the images inserted into posts/pages and link them to their file URLs?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.